# c# How to encode int array to TIFF image?

Tags: c#

I have int array with size [752*290].
I need encode Int32 array to TIFF image with 16bppGrayScale pixel format.
How can I do that?

p.s. integers in int array can be 0..65535 (brightness, I think)
I'm using WPF.

Comment: I think you need to be about 500% more detailed in your question. This is as wide as the blue sky.

Comment: What technology are you using wpf, winforms or asp.net?

Comment: Please be more specific first. Edit your post for details. Also, what code have you tried? Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code:

```
                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString))
                {
                    System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pf = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray16;
                    int stride = newImage.imageWidth * 2;
                    BitmapPalette pallet = BitmapPalettes.Gray16;
                    double dpix = 216;
                    double dpiy = 163;
                    BitmapSource bmpSource = BitmapSource.Create(imageWidth, imageHeight, dpix, dpiy, pf, pallet, intArray, stride);
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathString, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
                        encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.None;
                        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpSource));
                        encoder.Save(fs);
                    }

                }
```